# npm start react app not working on my project

Tags: javascript

I created a react app some weeks ago and it was working perfectly. now "npm start" now giving me the following errors

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src'
ERROR in ./src/App.js 13:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src'

ERROR in ./src/components/ProtectedRoute.js 7:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/StudentForm.js 6:0-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/components/StudentForm.js 8:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\components'

ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src'

ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:0-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/dist/antd.min.css' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src'    

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/EmployeeHome.js 5:0-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Login.js 5:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Login.js 10:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Register.js 5:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Register.js 10:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Students.js 8:0-29
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/pages/employees/Students.js 10:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-toast' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\pages\employees'

ERROR in ./src/redux/alerts.js 3:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@reduxjs/toolkit' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\redux'

ERROR in ./src/redux/employees.js 3:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@reduxjs/toolkit' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\redux'

ERROR in ./src/redux/store.js 4:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@reduxjs/toolkit' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MERN STACK PROJECT\STUDENTS RESULTS\client\src\redux'
```

[github](https://github.com/Eben4christ/stuedents-results-client-side)

I was expecting to see the react app open on my browser but it wasn't open.

I tried removing the node package and install back but yet not working.

Comment: Have you run `npm i` first?

Comment: You will have to install all node modules first then execute npm start. Give the command npm i

Comment: I have done this its still not working. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Before running your application, you need to install the dependencies first. Note, I recommend running `npm ci` instead of `npm install` to stick to the exact versions you defined in your lockfile.

```bash
npm ci
npm install react-hot-toast @reduxjs/toolkit antd
npm start
```

Comment: I have done this its still not working. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that there is an issue resolving the `react-hot-toast`, `@reduxjs/toolkit`, and `antd` modules in your project.
Install the packages

```js
npm install react-hot-toast @reduxjs/toolkit antd
```

Also in your package.json, you have ReactDOM 17, but in your `index.js` you use `ReactDOM.createRoot`, which is a function introduced in React 18.